# Picture post to Facebook ends up in the wrong place

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post a picture to Facebook page with id= 226338660793052, but it keeps ending up in /me/photos.  What am I doing wrong?

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   imageToSend, @"source",
                                   facebookMessageTextView.text, @"message",
                                   nil];
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"/226338660793052/photos" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

I get no error message.  I get nothing, except that the photo ends up in my own album, me/photos, and not in the album of 226338660793052/photos.

But when I just post a message to that page, I do get a successful post on the timeline of the page:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"http://www.bitsonthego.com", @"link",
                                   @"my profile", @"name",
                                   facebookMessageTextView.text, @"message",
                                   nil];
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"/226338660793052/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

What am I missing here?  I know this must be possible, as I can use a browser to upload a picture to the desired page, as a random non-admin user.  I just can't seem to do it from the graph API.

**UPDATE:**

I've resolved part of the issue.  You have to use the destination page's access_token.  This is how you get it:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"access_token",  @"fields",
                                   nil];
    FBRequest *request = [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"226338660793052" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

When you get the result, then you add it to the transaction above:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   image, @"source",
                                  [result objectForKey:@"access_token"], @"access_token",
                                   facebookMessageTextView.text, @"message",
                                   nil];

    FBRequest *request = [facebook requestWithGraphPath:[[result objectForKey:@"id"] stringByAppendingString:@"/photos"] andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

But, this won't work because Facebook.m will replace this new access_token with the default user access_token, so I made a change to Facebook.m at around line 166, from:

```
  if ([self isSessionValid]) {
        [params setValue:self.accessToken forKey:@"access_token"];
  }
```

to:

```
  if ([self isSessionValid]) {
    if ([params valueForKey:@"access_token"] == nil)
        [params setValue:self.accessToken forKey:@"access_token"];
  }
```

That keeps an access code you specify as part of the params, from getting clobbered by the Facebook.accessToken.  Now this will post the picture to the page I am interested in.

However, this works because I am an admin on the page in question.  Other users will not be able to post pictures and the pictures again will end up in their own albums, because the call to get an access_token for the page will return nil.

According to Facebook docs, if the page is unrestricted, as this page is, then it should be possible to post a picture to it:

> **NOTE:**
>
> For connections that require an access token, you can use any valid
>   access token if the page is public and not restricted. Connections on
>   restricted pages require a user access token and are only visible to
>   users who meet the restriction criteria (e.g. age) set on the page.

Did I mention that my page is public and not restricted?

> **Page Access Tokens**
>
> To perform the following operations as a Page, and not the current
>   user, you must use the Page's access token, not the user access token
>   commonly used for reading Graph API objects. This access token can be
>   retrieved by issuing an HTTP GET to /USER_ID/accounts with the
>   manage_pages permission. This will return a list of Pages (including
>   application profilePages) to which the user has administrative access,
>   along with access_tokens for those Pages. Alternatively, you can get a
>   page access token for a single, specific, page by issuing an HTTP GET
>   to /PAGE_ID?fields=access_token with themanage_pages permission, as
>   described above. Publishing to a Page also requires the publish_stream
>   permission, unless otherwise noted.

So how does one post a picture to a public/unrestricted page?  I can do it from any browser, so it is possible, but how is it done using the Graph API?  Given that I can post to the feed with no access_token shenanigans, what about posting a picture is different?

In summary, what I am trying to do is to post a picture, not just a thumbnail URL, to a public/non-restricted page, using the Graph API.

Comment: try to post into specified album using "ALBUM_ID/photos"

Comment: @mahboudz if its help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/6712526/1083859

Comment: @R.A a week after that SO question, on July 22, 2011, this was announced by Facebook:   https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/526/ :
This week we released the ability to attach existing Facebook photos from a user’s album to new posts on their Wall. To do this, issue an HTTP POST to USER_ID/feed with the Post object parameters. Include an object_attachment parameter which specifies the photo ID of the photo you wish to attach to the post. The User must be the owner of the photo, and the photo cannot be part of a message attachment.

Answer (score 4):

My issue as well at the moment! I believe the problem is with the lines in framework you rewrote, which became impossible since the Facebook SDK is now static library which can't be edited. However, I've figured out how to create the photos posts **without** having to change the SDK - I create new token data with the token string I get from an app:

```
FBAccessTokenData *tokenData = [FBAccessTokenData createTokenFromString:tokenString permissions:[FBSession activeSession].accessTokenData.permissions expirationDate:[FBSession activeSession].accessTokenData.expirationDate loginType:FBSessionLoginTypeFacebookApplication refreshDate:nil];
```

then I create new FBSession with fb appID (and nullCacheInstance, somehow it seems to be important):

```
FBSession *sessionFb = [[FBSession alloc] initWithAppID:appID permissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"publish_stream", @"manage_pages", nil] urlSchemeSuffix:nil tokenCacheStrategy:[FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy nullCacheInstance]];
```

and then I open the newly created session with tokenData created up, set this new session to be the active session, and it works!

```
[sessionFb openFromAccessTokenData:tokenData completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error)
 {
 }];

[FBSession setActiveSession:sessionFb];
```

Then calling request for PageAppID/photos with Post parameters and source image works, and it posts image on Facebook Page wall as being from itself!

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/photos", PageAppID] parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
 }];
```

I think the changing of activeSession is the thing that's similar to changing the lines in Facebook.m

hope this helps someone today

Answer (score 0):

Try posting to PAGE/posts instead of PAGE/photos, and adding a picture attribute to the post. The photos connection is for photos created by the page admins. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#posts for a full list of attributes on the posts connection.

Comment: This doesn't do it for me.  1) The image has to be uploaded someplace else first  2) Clicking on the image takes you to the link in the post instead of showing you a larger version of the image within Facebook.
3) I need the image to end up in the Page's album.

Comment: And I can't use a link to the image from my personal Facebook photo album.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if i understood your question wrongly.You could not directly post to wall.there is no method in the facebook API to achieve that.Check out this link.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

and below screenshot is taken from that link. [image]

Comment: You can post directly to walls:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

And you can post directly to Pages:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/
"photos:
Create

You can post photos to a Page's Wall by issuing an HTTP POST request to PAGE_ID/photos with the publish_stream and manage_pages permissions and the following parameters..."

Comment: Also, you can post pictures to a Page (and a wall) using both a browser, or the mobile app for FaceBook.  This does not seem to be a "private" API call given that they describe the process in the links I pasted above.  Posting to a wall is the problem, although the API call is supposed to be identical. "USER_ID/photos" works for both page and wall if I do it, but not if someone that is not an admin does it.