# iOS Facebook SDK - Posting A UIImage To User's Wall

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, uiimage

Ok so there is a lot of threads on this, but nothing seems to work for me.

My app allows users to post a photo (which is a UIImage created by a screenshot of the App) to facebook.

However, I can currently only post the photo by using:

```
    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[[appDelegate facebook] accessToken], @"access_token",nil];
    [params setObject:@"Caption" forKey:@"name"];
    [params setObject:[self captureScreen] forKey:@"source"];
    if([[appDelegate facebook] requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" andParams: params andHttpMethod: @"POST" andDelegate:(id)self]){
        [self.view addSubview:[Memos showMemo:facebookMemo]];//Show success alert
    }
```

This works fine, but doesn't use any sort of FB Dialog.
I really want to use the dialog so users can feel like it is more "facebook official" and allow them to preview/confirm the post.

Is there any SIMPLE way to go about doing this?
This is the closest I have gotten: [Post photo on user's wall using Facebook iOS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702135/post-photo-on-users-wall-using-facebook-ios-sdk), but I have issues with these lines:

```
currentAPICall = kAPIGraphUserPhotosPost;
```

As xcode doesnt recognize any of the kAPI... objects...
Suggestions?