# Facebook UI to display a photo upload available?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, user-interface, image-uploading, facebook-ios-sdk

i want to implement the Facebook SDK (not the 3.0 beta) to simple upload a photo to the users wall. I´ve found some good posts how to do that:
[Post photo on users wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702135/post-photo-on-users-wall-using-facebook-ios-sdk)

What i like to know is, if there´s already a Facebook UI when uploading the images or do i have to make my own activity indicator and react on the Facebook delegate methods?

I´m right, that there´s only a Facebook UI for displaying the dialog?
Like this:

```
 [appDelegate.facebook dialog:@"feed" 
                               andParams:dialogParams 
                             andDelegate:self];
```

Thanks for any help.
(Its my first Facebook integration, so i´m really looking forward to the easier iOS 6 integration ;))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to do that for yourself as the Facebook SDK does not currently provide a view for developers to use to upload a photo, and the new version of the SDK (3.0) also does not provide a view to use.

Comment: Ok, good to know. Thanks for your fast reply. Have a nice day.