# Facebook og:image

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

So i have a problem with the facebook og:image.

site: http://images.vallo-app.com/4db279b31df280b/

if people use this link to show their image, its no problem, facebook loads the og:image

But it is used in an iPhone App, so people make a picture and get a shortened url of bit.ly back and then they can post it.

So if you post it, facebook juts doesn't show the preview of the image, but if you post that shortened bit.ly link on facebook.com in the statusupdate it does. Someone know what the problem is?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to post an image status update, instead of a normal status update!

Comment: What do you mean by that? Which API calls were you / are you making?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702135/post-photo-on-users-wall-using-facebook-ios-sdk + it is about the type of the status update..