# ios - posting photo in user's facebook feed in sdk 3.14

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, facebook-sdk-3.14.x

Need help in uploading / posting photo in facebook in sdk 3.14.

Most of the working codes were deprecated in old sdk versions and i can't find a simple example of this.

[EDIT] Here's my current progress.

```
- (void) handleTakePictureTouch:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Take Picture");

    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =   [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
       [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    else
        [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];

    [imagePicker setDelegate:self];

    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}


- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    UIImage *img    =   [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [self.imgvPhoto setImage:img];
}


- (void) handleShareFacebook:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Share FB");

}
```

Comment: Specifically what help? Some code where you got stuck?

Comment: I'm not stuck at something. Honestly, i don't know how to implement this one and i need help on how to do it... Sorry, i didn't post what specific help i need

Comment: @user3755893 which tutorial have you followed?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: the answer of Sir Eric D'Souza here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702135/post-photo-on-users-wall-using-facebook-ios-sdk and this one - http://xcodenoobies.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/how-to-upload-photo-and-update-status.html

Comment: I've updated my question. I've already tried some of the links in my previous comment in handleShareFacebook method but none of those work. Please help, any docs, tuts for uploading photo in facebook sdk 3.14.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the docs, i've found a sample sharing in facebook sdk 3.14.x

here : https://github.com/fbsamples/ios-howtos/blob/master/FBShareSample/FBShareSample/ShareViewController.m