# Facebook iOS SDK how to get posted image id?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I found many online tutorial about how to post image to Facebook using Facebook iOS SDK, but i'm looking for a way to get posted image id. Is it returned with callback methods(if yes, then with which key) or is it even possible to get posted image id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When successfully uploading the image, you are given the url of the image (key:uri), you could work out the image id from that i guess.
Having the image url should be enough to work with.

Comment: On http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702135/post-photo-on-users-wall-using-facebook-ios-sdk see Eric D'Souza answer, he is getting image id. Is this correct?

Comment: check now, if you scroll down in his post you can see that he marked it as step 2(as comment)

Comment: So the way to do it is, to upload the photo the users album, this should return an id, you can then use this image id.

Comment: ok, thanks(and +1) for confirmation. let me check if i can do it as mention on that post.