# How do we get Post Id after sharing image or text on facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I am using latest Facebook SDK wanted to get post id after sharing image or text on Facebook.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please provide more details.

Comment: Working perfectlay solved the issue now :NSMutableDictionary* photosParams = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: imgSource,@"source",strMessage,@"message",nil][[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                                             parameters:photosParams
                                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"]
           startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
               if ([error.userInfo[FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphErrorCode] isEqual:@200]) {

               }
           }];

Answer (score 1):

After posting on facebook successfully . In your

-(void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result

method you will get the result.. Get the results. You will get the post_id if you are using FB SSO

Answer (score 0):

you can try
 did this in three steps

1 post picture to album (returns imageID)

2 use imageID to request metadata for imageID

3 use the 'link' field (not the 'source' field) as a link to the image in a post to the user's wall

The downside is that there are now two posts to the wall, one for the image, and one for the actual post. I haven't figured out yet how to post a picture to an album, without also a wall post appearing (ideally it would just be the 2nd post that appears)

[Post photo on user's wall using Facebook iOS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702135/post-photo-on-users-wall-using-facebook-ios-sdk)