# Can't get photo id with Facebook API

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using this code for posting image, but don't get image ID in response.

```
FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
photo.image = self.image.image;
photo.userGenerated = YES;
FBSDKSharePhotoContent *content = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];
content.photos = @[photo];
[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self
                             withContent:content
                                delegate:self];
```

Comment: Title changed, code formatted, tag added

Comment: Tried posting to album? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8330084/1081340

Comment: Now I get photo Id by using this lines of code ->  NSMutableDictionary* photosParams = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:imgSource,@"source",strMessage,@"message",nil];                                                              [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"parameters:photosParams HTTPMethod:@"POST"]
           startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
               if ([error.userInfo[FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphErrorCode] isEqual:@200]) {    }  }];

Comment: That code should work. What error are you getting?